# Best way to deploy a mobile Powerpoint Add In

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

Do any of you know what the best way is to deploy a mobile Powerpoint Add-In?

I developed an add-in that logs the time whenever a teacher switches slides, and also exports all the slides as separate JPEG files. This is necessary, because we also record the presentations on video, and want to combine the two using a second-screen. The whole back-end behind this is finished and is working (but we need to manually type in the positions of the 'slide'. So we figured we could automate this).

The users the add in needs to run on don't have any Administrator rights, and we don't have access to the administrator account either (this is in an Educational environment). But we do need to launch a Powerpoint application with the add in already installed, so we can record the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write a few entries to the registry, in HKEY_CurrentUser?  Specifically:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\YourAddinName

Under that, add a new

String:  Path = the full path to your add-in's PPA/PPAM file
DWORD:   AutoLoad = ffff ffff hex

That will cause PPT to load your add-in automatically when it starts up.